# PHP file execution timout when running with terminal

Tags: timeout, php

I want to run a `.php` file via terminal (I have CentOS), so I want to know is there any limitation in execution time when I run the `.php` files with terminal, and not Apache?

Comment: how long is it taking before it timeouts? 30 seconds?

Comment: @Landon I didn't run the script before, but `max_execution_time` is `30`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Time limit should be the same. See `max_execution_time` in your `php.ini`. You can force it with `set_time_limit(90)` in your php code for example.

Comment: Doesn't Apache also enforce its own limit too?

Comment: So, I couldn't find `time_limit` in my `php.ini`, but `max_execution_time` is `30`.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Change it or force with `set_time_limit(n)`

Comment: @jadkik94 that's other thing.. That's Apache's timeout value.. It usually does not make problems.

Comment: Just a silly thing! Now, it's about 12 minutes that I've run the script with `sudo php -f index.php` and it's working now! Is this a unusual behavior?

Comment: @Afshin Mehrabani I would advice you to find the reason why it takes so long to execute script. Measure critical places. If the difference between executing from cli and browser is great, there is something wrong..

Comment: @BogdanBurim Ok, let me say. I didn't run it from browser and Apache before and it's not needed, I just want to run the php file from Terminal. Remember, its not a website page. So, I just need to run it via terminal, and let the script to do its job, I'm going to work with about 20,000,000 data and this is why it takes so long.

Comment: In this case everything is fine. Use `set_time_limit(0)` to disable time limitations and have fun!

Answer (score 2):

You can set that value to 0:

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

This will prevent timeouts entirely.  Be careful though.  The time outs are in there for a purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use set_time_limit(n) in your script http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php